# Does the Client ID of Firebase Cloud Messaging Change when the Client Switches Device or Opens a new Session in the Browser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This question is rather conceptual. I just need some clarifications.

As far as I know, when using FCM, the backend server sends the message payload with clientIds (not talking about topic-based implementation),  to FCM which will then distribute the message across to all the clients with the kids specified. For the frontend in the browsers, you then embed the Firebase SDK to receive the message.

My question is does the client ID change when the user opens a new session in the browser (or using incognito) or use a new device (browser on phone or the other computer)?

So does the client send the id to the backend? Can someone also send my clients message s if they have my clients' ids? Or firebase prevents that?

If that's the case how do I know which client has its changed ID changed? So I can deliver the correct messages?

Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID is a device token, so it will indeed be different for a new device.

A new browser session for the same user will not result in a new token, but an incognito browser is a new "users" so will get its own token.

Comment: So does the client send the id to the backend? Can someone also send my clients message s if they have my clients' ids? Or firebase prevents that?

Comment: You need to know the FCM server key of the project to send messages to clients, which is a trusted resource.